# Show that there exist positive constants $a$, $b$ such that $|f(x)| \leq a |x| + b$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

**Problem**

For a uniformly continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, show that there exist positive constants $a$, $b$ such that $|f(x)| \leq a |x| + b$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Progress**

This problem is confusing me greatly.

Suppose $f(0)=\alpha$.
Then define $g(x)=f(x)-\alpha$ so we have $g(0)=0$.

$g$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ also, and I feel it will be of more use to us, but I really have no idea where to go with this. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the definition of uniform continuity?

Comment: @Eckhard Yes, though I can't see how it would be applied in this context...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By uniform continuity there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$
|x-y|\le\delta\implies|f(x)-f(y)|\le1.
$$
If $x\in[0,\delta]$ then
$$
|f(x)-f(0)|\le1\implies|f(x)|\le1+|f(0)|.
$$
If $x\in[\delta,2\,\delta]$ then
$$
|f(x)-f(\delta)|\le1\implies|f(x)|\le1+|f(\delta)|\le2+|f(0)|.
$$
Use induction to prove that if $x\in[(n-1)\delta,n\,\delta]$ then
$$
|f(x)|\le n+|f(0)|\le \frac{x}{\delta}+1+|f(0)|.
$$
A similar argument applies to the case $x<0$.